# I can't get my search form and result views to render - using Thinking-sphinx along side existing search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, rails-routing

I have a 2.3.11 Rails app, and I would like to add a fulltext search to be able to search on the 'articles' content and title.  I am using Thinking-sphinx for this purpose.  I just want to be able to click on the search link_to '/advanced_search' (on the home page) and have the search form come up, then once the search form is submitted have another view search_results.html.erb display a list of matching article(s).

Problem:  I found out that I really don't understand how views are actually rendered.  I'm also not sure I got my routing correct.  I've tried different things, but for some reason all the examples I found out there are different.

So I have a search form /controllers/articles_controller/advanced_search :

```
<% form_tag :controller => 'articles', :action => 'search', :method => 'get' do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :id => 'search_field' %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Search', :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

And I have a second view to display the search results, /controllers/articles_controller/search_results.html.erb:

```
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
  <li><%= link_to article.name, :action => 'show', :id => article.id %></li>
  <li><%= article.archived? %></li>
<% end %>
```

This my model where I define the index for sphinx:

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name
  #rest of validation and associations here

define_index do
    indexes summary
    indexes :name
  end
 end

This my controller and new search action  /controllers/articles_controller:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
```

load_and_authorize_resource

def index
    @articles = Article.all

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @articles }
  format.json  { render :json => @articles }
end
```

end

def search
    @articles = Article.search params[:search]

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # 
  format.xml  { render :xml => @articles }
  format.json  { render :json => @articles }
end
```

end
end

In my routes.rb I have this line, which is probably not correct, but when I take it out, I get the routing error 'No route matches "/advance_search" with {method => get}

```
map.connect 'advance_search', :controller => "articles, :action => search
```

I would appreciate any ideas on how to have my views render correctly, assuming that everything else is correct.

Answer (score 0):

one of the issues that messed me up was the fact that nested routing was I think over used.  I found a way around this problem for now.  I would have loved to leave a straight answer for anyone with the same question, but unfortunately, my solution does not answer this particular question since I went about it a completely different way.  I did however notice later that there are other similar questions that were in fact answered.